# Need to assign dynamic string value to @PactFolder annotation in Java-Pact Contract test

Tags: java, junit4, junit5, pact

I need to add a variable value to a class-level annotation "@PactFolder" in a JUnit test. I've been able to achieve the dynamic assignment for this annotation using simple reflection in the @BeforeClass method.

However, This JUnit contract test runs with another annotation (@RunWith(PactRunner.class)). Now, since the @PactFolder annotation's purpose is to pass an absolute path to the PactRunner class, and PactRunner reads the value of @PactFolder at the time of invocation, the reflected variable value is of no use.

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactSource;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.HttpTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.TestTarget;

@PactFolder("<Dynamic value>")
@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("CvSaveDataServiceProvider")
public class ContractTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setConditions() {
    PactFolder pactFolder = ContractTest.class.getAnnotation(PactFolder.class);
    AlterPactFolderAnnotation.setAbsolutePactDirectory(ContractTest.class, PactFolder.class, ContractDirectoryRelativeModulePath.HRIS.getRelativeModulePath(), pactFolder);

     System.out.println(ContractTest.class.getAnnotation(PactFolder.class).value()); 
    }

    @TestTarget 
    public HttpTarget target = new HttpTarget(8080);
}
```

I need to access contracts from a locally cloned repository, kept in multiple directories, with final aim to add paths of all directories in a single config file and initialize all tests in different directories from a single point using "mvn test" command (a simple batch file)

Is there a possible solution or any workaround to do this ?